# css - descendant child element clipped by parent element

Tags: html, css

In [this](http://biztest.netai.net/) WordPress site, I am trying to get the:

```
<section id="content">
```

<sub>the box with the main text</sub>

To overlap the top boundary of its parent

```
<div id="container">
```

When I add `top:-200px` to the section's style, it gets clipped by the above picture. The only way to prevent the clipping is to edit the ancestor `<div id="wrapper">` by removing from it:

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

But this also removes the white background. I need no clipping+ yes background, but can only get clipping+background, or no clipping+no background.

Here is my site: http://biztest.netai.net

If logging into the site will help, I can send you the login info.

Comment: Can you put down relevant code rather than requiring us to go to your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can follow that way:

- Set `top:-200px` on the section.
- Remove the `overflow-x:hidden` on the wrapper.

The problem cames here:

> Why the white background is been removed?

Because you aren't using [`clear`](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) method after float the section then the container and the wrapper seems to have `height:0`. You can add this to your CSS after the previous modifications:

```
#container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Screenshot after do that modifications with DeveloperTools:

[image]